# Unable to determine which code is executed on button click

Tags: javascript, html

There is a website which has a two small `<-` `->` buttons for navigation, and their HTML code is like this:

`<-`:

```
<a class="left prev browse" href="javascript:;">&lt;</a>
```

`->`:

```
<a class="right next browse" href="javascript:;">&gt;</a>
```

What I don't understand is how is there JavaScript being triggered here ? What event/function is being called ?

I can't figure out what event/function is triggered when we click the `<-` `->` buttons. How are the messages sliding ?

**URL:** http://bit.ly/16447fr (To avoid search engine indexing)

**This is where these  `<-` `->` buttons are used:**

[image]

Comment: check external javascript files and inline javascript codes. there should be some event listeners for some of these classes: right next browse

Comment: Search the source for other occurrences of "right", "left" or "browse".  "onclick" handlers are probably assigned after the page loads by JavaScript.  Are you able to determine what libraries this page uses?  Look for things like `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Maybe the event handler is being attached via jQuery, when the document is ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your site there is used the library of javasript its jQuery and thru which the next and pre are working the code is written in the **jquery.cycle.all.2.74.pack.js** file which is library of jQuery.

You can find this functionality in this file.

You can see that there is two case in switch. these are:

```
case "prev":
case "next":
```

In these case the next and pre buttons code is written.

Comment: But that is a third party file. Where is the Cycle plugin being called from ?

Comment: @Ahmad right this is third party file but according to its code. to slide the banner you have define your HTML code like you have given the class name in anchor tag as per define. this code it running on page load.

Comment: Where is the `case "prev"; case "next";` code ? I don't see that code present in **jquery.cycle.all.2.74.pack.js**

Comment: In fact, I don't see `case "prev"; case "next";` in any JS file being used by the site. And its also not in the HTML too ..

Comment: @Ahmad open the file and find it there I got this code from there.

Comment: There is no `case` in **jquery.cycle.all.2.74.pack.js**

Comment: I am looking at **jquery.cycle.all.2.74.pack.js** .. I'm using notepad++ to find any instance of the keyword `case` in it .. I don't get any hits ..

Comment: @Ahmad check this link http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/js/jquery.cycle.all.2.74.pack.js I got this JS file from your site link.

Comment: Alright, I see it .. For some reason if I deminify the code, that `case` goes away for some reason :/ .. Anyways, if I need to reproduce this elsewhere, do I need to do anything other than import this js file, along with jQuery etc, assuming that I keep the same HTML code ? .. Would I need a document.ready function to manually assign a listener or something ?

Comment: @Ahmad no need to define document.ready if you want to use it anywhere else. although you need to give the class name and other HTML tag according to documentation of this library.

Comment: Alright .. Well I'm actually trying to replicate the effect separately here: http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/2NJUs/4/, but the `<-` `->` buttons are not working .. I've important the same JS, added jQuery, and also have kept the same HTML markup .. So technically it should work, but its not working .. If you can diagnose this too, I'd be very grateful .. In either case, I'll mark this as the answer ..

Comment: @Ahmad as I have also seen the fiddle. that is not working. I think there will be issue in accessing the JS. So I will suggest you to try it on your own machine.

Answer (score 1):

They will be adding the event listeners in some javascript code after the page has loaded. Something like:

```
var leftButton = document.getElementsByClassName('left prev')[0];
leftButton.addEventlistener('click', function(event){...});
```

or in JQuery:

```
$('.left.prev').on('click', function(event){...});
```